# Making a button do the cmd + h command

Tags: objective-c, macos, hide

Hey, I was wondering if it's possible to make a button do the cmd + h command?

This is how I was thinking.
The app will get the information as the force quit does (Apple Logo > Force Quit)
The user selected the app the user would like to hide and instead of having a force quit button I was thinking about having a hide button that does the cmd + h.

Would this be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean hide the application you are running in, or hide a different application on the system? To hide the application you are in, attach the button to either the application's or first responder's hide: method. If you want to hide a different application, you have to send a hide apple event to the application.